# Android: Button doesn't work, but code doesn't show any error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-camera

I'm trying to create a form to capture data, I need to access the camera to take pictures. My problem is when I try to call the camera with `imagenButton`, it's not working but the code doesn't show any error.

Here's my `fragment` to declare form:

```
public class EspecimenesInsertarFragment extends Fragment implements 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
private EspecimenesViewModel especimenesViewModel;
RequestQueue rq;
JsonRequest jrq;

final int COD_SELECCIONA=10;
final int COD_FOTO=20;

private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAMERA=101;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA=101;

Button btnGuardar, btnCancelar;
ImageButton btnCamara, btnGaleria;
ImageView imageView;
public static final int MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 50000;


public EspecimenesInsertarFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static EspecimenesInsertarFragment newInstance() { return new EspecimenesInsertarFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_colecciones_insertar, container, false);
    imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btnCamara=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.tomarFoto);
    btnGuardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIngresarEspecimenes);
    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());


  /*  if(validaPermisos()){
        btnCamara.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        btnCamara.setEnabled(false);
    } */

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
    }


    btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registrar_especimen("http://localhost/BIO-UES-APP/EspecimenesController.php");
        }
    });
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO=1;

public void tomarFoto(View view){
    Intent takePictureInent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Log.d("entra","");
    if(takePictureInent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())!= null){
        File photoFile=null;
        try {
            photoFile=createImageFile();
        }catch (IOException ex){

    }
        if(photoFile!=null){
        Uri photoUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),"com.example.luvin.drawercero",photoFile);
        takePictureInent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoUri);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureInent,REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Especimenes.EspecimenesConsultarFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-7dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="393dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="79dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tomarFoto"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/seleccionarDesdeGaleria"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />


        </FrameLayout>
        
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonCancelarEspecimenes"
                android:layout_width="129dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonIngresar"
                android:backgroundTint="#96A6A8"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="CANCELAR"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.783"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.659" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonIngresarEspecimenes"
                android:layout_width="129dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
                android:text="INGRESAR"
                app:backgroundTint="#00BCD4"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonCancelar"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.659" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Logcat message when button is pressed:

```
com.example.luvin.drawercero D/ViewRootImpl@6731d38[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

To complete my question, I have the permissions in the manifest. I already tried to call the camera in another way, tried creating the method in the `MainActivity` to create the `OnClick` event in the XML Layout, but nothing works.
If anyone knows how to solve this issue please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot to add your `tomarFoto` function to the button's callback.

Comment: Something like this?
    `btnCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
            `@Override`
            `public void onClick(View v) {`
                `tomarFoto(this);`
            `}`
        `});`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the on click listener to your photo button. This should solve your problem:

```
btnCamara = view.findViewById(R.id.tomarFoto);
btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tomarFoto(v);
    }
});
```